# Python parallel testing with serial grouped tests

Tags: multithreading, pytest, python-3.10

How to run all tests in serial per host while each host is in a single thread.

maybe some code will explain what I'm trying to do.

`conftest.py`

```py
from paramiko import SSHClient, AutoAddPolicy
from shared import Host, HOSTS
from pytest import fixture
from typing import Dict

FMT = '[%(name)s %(levelname)-7s(%(lineno)-4d)][%(threadName)s] %(message)s'

@fixture(scope="session")
def _ssh_con(request) -> Dict[Host, SSHClient]:
    print('>>>>>>>> setup')
    cons: Dict[Host, SSHClient] = {}
    for item in request.session.items:
        host = item.callspec.params.get("host")
        if host not in cons:
            con = SSHClient()
            con.set_missing_host_key_policy(AutoAddPolicy())
            con.connect(host.ip, host.port, host.username, host.password)
            cons[host] = con

    print('>>>>>>>> setup done')
    yield cons
    print('<<<<<<<<<< teardown')
    for value in cons.values():
        value.close()
    print('<<<<<<<<<< teardown done')


@fixture(autouse=True)
def ssh(host: Host, _ssh_con: Dict[Host, SSHClient], logger) -> SSHClient:
    rp_logger.info(f'yield {host}')
    yield _ssh_con[host]


def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc: Metafunc):
    metafunc.parametrize('host', HOSTS, ids=str)

@fixture(scope="session")
def logger() -> logging.Logger:
    logger = logging.getLogger('Tester')
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    fmt = logging.Formatter(FMT)
    hdlr = logging.StreamHandler()
    hdlr.setFormatter(fmt)
    logger.addHandler(hdlr)
    return logger
```

`shared.py`

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import List


@dataclass()
class Host:
    name: str
    ip: str
    port: int = field(repr=False, default=22)
    username: str = 'myusername'
    password: str = field(repr=False, default='myuserpassowrd')

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.ip)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


HOSTS: List[Host] = [
    Host('Host-1', '192.168.195.1'),
    Host('Host-2', '192.168.195.2'),
    Host('Host-3', '192.168.195.3'),
]
```

`tests.py`

```py
from time import sleep
from paramiko import SSHClient
from shared import Host, HOSTS


SLEEP_TIME = 2

def test_ip(ssh: SSHClient, host: Host, logger):
    logger.info(f"test_ip[{host}][{ssh}]")
    command = "ip a s ens33 | grep 'inet ' | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d'/' -f1"
    sleep(SLEEP_TIME)
    _, stdout, _ = ssh.exec_command(command)
    output = stdout.read().decode('utf8').strip()
    assert output == host.ip, "got un expected IP or didn't get any IP"


def test_machine_name(host: Host, ssh: SSHClient, logger):
    logger.info(f"test_machine_name[{host}][{ssh}]")
    command = f"ls /tmp | grep {host.name}"
    sleep(SLEEP_TIME)
    _, stdout, _ = ssh.exec_command(command)
    output = stdout.read().decode('utf8').strip()
    assert output, "didn't find file with host name"
```

What I want to achieve is the following:
Create all ssh connections for the session
start pytest_runtestloop
start Thread-1, Thread-2, Thread-3
for each thread start all tests in sequential order
Teardown all ssh connections for the session

I tried to use `pytest-parallel` and `pytest-xdist` (which doesn't fit my use case)
I also tried to write my own plugin, but I'm not able to get it right.
In the log output, I get that the thread name is MainThread _/(**)\_

```py
from concurrent.futures import Future, ThreadPoolExecutor, wait
from typing import Dict, List

from shared import Host

WITH_SUB_THREAD = True


def _run_hosts_tests(session, host, tests):
    if WITH_SUB_THREAD:
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(1, f"Worker_{host}") as executor:
            for test_idx in tests:
                item = session.items[test_idx]
                executor.submit(item.runtest)
    else:
        for test_idx in tests:
            item = session.items[test_idx]
            item.runtest()


def _done_callback(future: Future):
    try:
        result = future.result()
        print(f"[\033[92;1mOK\033[0m] {result}")
        return result
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"[\033[91;1mERR\033[0m] {e}")
        raise e


class ParallelRunner:
    def __init__(self):
        self._tests_mapper: Dict[Host, List[int]] = dict()

    def pytest_collection_finish(self, session):
        for idx, item in enumerate(session.items):
            host = item.callspec.getparam('host')

            if host not in self._tests_mapper:
                self._tests_mapper[host] = []

            self._tests_mapper[host].append(idx)

    def pytest_runtestloop(self, session):
        if (
            session.testsfailed
            and not session.config.option.continue_on_collection_errors
        ):
            raise session.Interrupted(
                "%d error%s during collection"
                % (session.testsfailed, "s" if session.testsfailed != 1 else "")
            )

        if session.config.option.collectonly:
            return True

        with ThreadPoolExecutor(len(self._tests_mapper), 'Worker') as executor:
            for host, tests in self._tests_mapper.items():
                executor.submit(_run_hosts_tests, session, host, tests)\
                    .add_done_callback(_done_callback)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was it set the connection in a global variable,
although I'm sure that there is a better solution, in the meantime I will put this workaround here.

`conftest.py`

```py
from threading import Lock

_cons: Dict[Host, SSHClient] = dict()


@fixture(scope="session")
def _ssh_con(request: SubRequest) -> Dict[Host, SSHClient]:
    mutex.acquire()
    global _cons
    if not _cons:
        for item in request.session.items:
            host = item.callspec.params.get("host")
            if host not in _cons:
                con = SSHClient()
                con.set_missing_host_key_policy(AutoAddPolicy())
                con.connect(host.ip, host.port, host.username, host.password)
                _cons[host] = con


    mutex.release()
    return _cons


def pytest_sessionfinish(session, exitstatus):
    mutex.acquire()
    global _cons
    if _cons:
        for value in _cons.values():
            value.close()
    mutex.release()
```